# MSGraphAPI - Invoke-RestMethod - SendMail - Multiple Reciepents

Tags: json, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I´m using MS Graph API `sendMail` and I want to add more than 1 user as Recipient. With 2 users it´s working, but don´t have an idea how to add more then 2 persons.

My Invoke-RestMethod Code is:

```
$BodyJsonsend = @"
                    {
                        "message": {
                            "subject": "$($Subject)",
                            "body": {
                                "contentType": "HTML",
                                "content": "$($Body)"
                            },
                            "toRecipients": [
                                {
                                    "emailAddress": {
                                        "address": "mail1@domain.com"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "ccRecipients": [
                                {
                                    "emailAddress": {
                                    "address": "mail2@domain.com"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "emailAddress": {
                                    "address": "mail3@domain.com"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "saveToSentItems": "true"
                    }
"@
```

Can someone tell me, how the json should look like? The JSON above isn´t working.

I also tried the following json

```
"ccRecipients": [
    {
        "emailAddress": {
        "address": "mail2@domain.com"
        },
        "emailAddress": {
        "address": "mail3@domain.com"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I see no Invoke-Restmethod in your code. You are simply showing a json. Please (re)-read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then update your post with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Could you share how you call Invoke-Rest? You say that it's working for 2 users but not for 3 and more. Is it correct? What exception do you receive?

Answer (score 0):

My Invoke-Restmethod call is:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $URLsend -Headers $headers -Body $BodyJsonsend
```

The URL is

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sender@domain.com/sendMail
```

I don´t get an error message. The Response is 202 Accepted. I triggered the Post via Postman and there it´s working. So the correct code is:

```
$BodyJsonsend = @"
                    {
                        "message": {
                            "subject": "$($Subject)",
                            "body": {
                                "contentType": "HTML",
                                "content": "$($Body)"
                            },
                            "toRecipients": [
                                {
                                    "emailAddress": {
                                        "address": "mail1@domain.com"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "ccRecipients": [
                                {
                                    "emailAddress": {
                                    "address": "mail2@domain.com"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "emailAddress": {
                                    "address": "mail3@domain.com"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "saveToSentItems": "true"
                    }
"@
```

Yesteday it doesn´t worked...
Thanks for support.